# Запрос с количественной выборкой

Tags: sql

Имеется вот такая структура бд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно вывести определенную группу если в ней больше 5 пользователей, попробовал такой запрос, но он не работает:

```
SELECT GROUP.NAME 
  FROM GROUP
  JOIN USER_GROUP 
    ON GROUP.ID = USER_GROUP.GROUP_ID
 WHERE USER_GROUP.GROUP_ID = '3'
HAVING COUNT(USER_GROUP.GROUP_ID = '3') > 5
```

Как исправить?

Comment: ну проверить то вам надо больше 5 _пользователей_? почему в having у вас группы тогда? `having count(user_id) > 5`

Comment: Сейчас Mike придёт и скажет как правильно. Здесь нужно использовать `GROUP BY GROUP.ID`, `WHERE USER_GROUP.GROUP_ID = '3'` - убрать, `HAVING COUNT(USER_GROUP.GROUP_ID = '3') > 5` заменить на `HAVING COUNT(*) > 5`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP.NAME 
  FROM GROUP
  JOIN USER_GROUP
    ON GROUP.ID = USER_GROUP.GROUP_ID
 WHERE USER_GROUP.GROUP_ID = '3'
 GROUP BY GROUP.ID
HAVING COUNT(USER_GROUP.USER_ID) > 5
```